# GoogleTest - error E0145 - "google::protobuf::internal::ExtensionSet::kMaximumFlatCapacity" may not be initialized

Tags: c++, linker-errors, googletest

I was adding some code to a project and wanted to add a Google Test case for it, on the unit testing project called UnitTests. Everything was going fine, my test failed because of some silly copy+paste mistake I made but after I fixed it I couldn't run the test anymore because during the build stage I'd get this error

> Error (active)    E0145   member
> "google::protobuf::internal::ExtensionSet::kMaximumFlatCapacity" may
> not be initialized    UnitTests

Which stems from google\protobuf\extension_set.h.

and

> Error LNK1104 cannot open file '\UnitTests.exe'

I commented-out my new test and tried to rebuild but encountered the same issue.
Then I tried to change to a different branch in my local repository - one without any of that new code and building the unit tests project still resulted in the same issue.

What could be the problem?

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 if it could matter.

Thanks.

Comment: "cannot open file '\UnitTests.exe'" often means that the executable is still running, perhaps from the last debugging session. Check with Task Manager.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yup, that did the trick.
What a silly mistake to make.
Thank you!